# What is the probability of $\lfloor a+b \rfloor < \lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor$

Tags: real-numbers

Given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a\ge0, b\ge0$, what is the probability of:

$$
\lfloor a+b \rfloor < \lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor
$$

Comment: Hint: without loss of generality $a,b \in [0,1]$

Comment: First try to find an example of $\lfloor a+b \rfloor < \lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor\geq 0$ then 
$$\lfloor a+b \rfloor=\lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor+ \underbrace{\lfloor \{a\}+\{b\}\rfloor}_{\geq 0}\geq \lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor.$$
Hence the given inequality is NEVER satisfied!